# Error when I compile 'hello-world' example from Contiki

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, contiki

I have installed the Contiki OS sources, and the ARM GCC compiler by doing `brew install arm-none-eabi-gcc`. However, when I try to run the hello world example in Contiki's example folder using the command `make TARGET=srf06-cc26xx BOARD=sensortag/cc2650 hello-world.bin CPU_FAMILY=cc26xx`, I get the following error message:

```
  CC        ../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/startup_files/ccfg.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized -march target: core2
arm-none-eabi-gcc: note: valid arguments are: armv4 armv4t armv5t armv5te armv5tej armv6 armv6j armv6k armv6z armv6kz armv6zk armv6t2 armv6-m armv6s-m armv7 armv7-a armv7ve armv7-r armv7-m armv7e-m armv8-a armv8.1-a armv8.2-a armv8.3-a armv8.4-a armv8.5-a armv8-m.base armv8-m.main armv8-r iwmmxt iwmmxt2
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: missing argument to '-march='
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mssse3'
make: *** [obj_srf06-cc26xx/ccfg.o] Error 1
```

I triple-checked that the ARM GCC compiler is accessible from the terminal by doing `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version`, and I can see that it is properly installed:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599]
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So I am really not sure what might be wrong here. Can anyone help?

My operating system is macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6.

UPDATE: The makefile is given in the example folder (from contiki):

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-world
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

CONTIKI = ../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

UPDATE 2: By adding `V=1` in the command, my output is:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize
 -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -DCONTIKI=1 
-DCONTIKI_TARGET_SRF06_CC26XX=1 -DNETSTACK_CONF_WITH_IPV6=1 
-DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL=1 -DBOARD_SENSORTAG=1 -DBACKDOOR_IOID=0x00000000 
-I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx
/lib/cc26xxware/driverlib -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/inc 
-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
 -fshort-enums -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -std=c99 -O2
  -I. -I../../platform/srf06-cc26xx/. -I../../platform/srf06-cc26xx
/sensortag/cc2650 -I../../platform/srf06-cc26xx/sensortag -I../../platform
/srf06-cc26xx/common -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/. -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/dev 
-I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/rf-core -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/rf-core/api -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/startup_files -I../..
/cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/../arm/common/dbg-io -I../../core/dev -I../../core/lib -I../../core/net -I../../core/net/llsec -I../../core/net/mac -I../..
/core/net/rime -I../../core/net/rpl -I../../core/sys -I../../core/cfs 
-I../../core/ctk -I../../core/lib/ctk -I../../core/loader -I../../core/. -I../../core/sys -I../../core/dev -I../../core/lib -I../../core/net/ipv6 -I../../core/net/ip -I../../core/net/rpl -I../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx
/lib/cc26xxware/driverlib -I../../core/net -I../../core/net/mac -I../..
/core/net/mac/contikimac -I../../core/net/llsec -I../../platform/srf06-
cc26xx/ -I../.. -DCONTIKI_VERSION_STRING=\"Contiki-3.x-3345-g32b5b17\" 
-include "contiki-conf.h" -c ../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware
/startup_files/ccfg.c -o obj_srf06-cc26xx/ccfg.o
```

UPDATE 3: If I do `unset CFLAGS`, I get a new error message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/9-2019-q4-major/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: hello-world.elf section `.interp' will not fit in region `FLASH_CCFG'
/usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/9-2019-q4-major/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: region `FLASH_CCFG' overflowed by 9120 bytes
/usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/9-2019-q4-major/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol ad_strip_dylibs; defaulting to 0000000000000000
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello-world.elf] Error 1
rm obj_srf06-cc26xx/startup_gcc.o hello-world.co obj_srf06-cc26xx/fault-handlers.o
```

Comment: Well it states that it does not recognize your target. Are you sure that board is supported by this toolchain? How the make file looks?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the board is supported by this toolchain. As a matter of fact, it was working fine a few days ago, but I was working on some other project and I am not sure if something I installed wrecked my set-up. @Eraklon I added the makefile in the post too

Comment: The first part of the compilation flags (before `-DCONTIKI=1`) comes from somewhere else. Maybe you have `CFLAGS` variable set in your shell? Try running `unset CFLAGS`

Comment: @kfx that gave me a new error message (see updated post)

Comment: Perhaps you also need to unset LDFLAGS and run `make clean`? :)

Comment: @kfx Amazing!! Doing `unset CFLAGS`, followed by `unset LDFLAGS` and lastly `make clean` resolved the issue. If you write an answer for this post (with some brief explanations), I'll accept it as the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a consolidation of @kfx's solution (which worked like a charm):

1. `unset CFLAGS`
2. `unset LDFLAGS`
3. `make clean`

This is because there may be some other flags which you accidentally set previously, so you have to unset them in order for the compilation to work.